# How to create runnable jar with images and sounds in Eclipse?

Tags: javafx, jar, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create a jar in eclipse. The project contains images and sounds.
I have Resources folder with more folders, but when I run the jar is without the images.

The project structure:

[image]

Example:

```
btServer.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("file:Resources/buttonimages/Server.png",100,100,false,false)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you are exporting your Runnable JAR file, you are selecting 'extracting required libraries into generated JAR'.

The other workaround is to put the resources folder from your workspace in the same file location as your jar file.

Hope this helps